# Query to find the SSIS package run schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have created a SQL Server 08 database maintenance plan using the Wizard.

The job shows in the msdb.sysjobs table but it doesn't show the schedule in the msdb.sysjobschedules table because the Wizard created it as an SSIS package. - fine

Then I go to the msdb.sysssispackages and I can see the package there but nothing about the next scheduled run date.

My question is if it is possible to create a query to get the job schedule for that type of job. Something as simple as next_run_date like in the sysjobschedules table.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have scheduled the plan? (First page of the wizard)

Comment: Yes, I have scheduled the plan in the first page of the wizard.

Comment: For me it shows up in `sysjobschedules `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans p
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans sp
         ON p.id = sp.plan_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules j
         ON j.schedule_id = sp.schedule_id
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. The job for the Maintenance plan created with the wizard still do not show the in the msdb.sysjobschedules table. However I was able to locate them inside the msdb.sysjobactivity table column name: next_scheduled_run_date. I will mark your answer accepted. Thank you.